# Avoid second method execution before first method execution is complete?

Tags: c#, asp.net, thread-safety

In Asp.Net, I am calling two methods, in which the first method is generating files by using exe and the second one is taking those generated files as input. Here the issues is, the second method is calling before the first method execution is complete. How should I avoid this?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CallEXE();
        ProcessFiles("filepath");
    }
    private void CallEXE()
    {
        // it generates files and stored the file in shared folder.
        Process.Start("FileGenerator.Exe");

    }
    private void ProcessFiles(string filePath)
    {
        //processing files
    }
```

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks,
Lenin

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Process.WaitForExit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Process FileGenerator;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CallEXE();
    ProcessFiles("filepath");
}
private void CallEXE()
{
    // it generates files and stored the file in shared folder.
    FileGenerator = Process.Start("FileGenerator.Exe");

}
private void ProcessFiles(string filePath)
{
    FileGenerator.WaitForExit();
    //processing files
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its working.